# Is there a finite abelian group $G$ such that $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ is abelian but $G$ is not cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example in which $G$ is a finite abelian group and $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ is abelian but $G$ not cyclic?

Comment: Please explain why this is downvoted, if I am just interested in an example?

Comment: Please, try to make the title of your question more informative. E.g., *Is there a finite abelian group $G$ such that $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ is abelian but not cyclic?* is much more useful for other users than *Example in Group Theory*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: In the spirit of the previous comment, would you like it if someone simply answered your question with "yes" or "no"? That's as useful as your title is.

Comment: I am no longer interested, I will figure it out myself. I thought there was maybe a quick example, but apparently there are only psuedo-witty comment. I am here for the mathematics.

Comment: If you google "abelian automorphism group" then you can find pages (on mathoverflow, for instance) with answers that address your question.

Comment: This provides the yes answer that you wanted to tell me

Comment: @SimonS: I was almost fooled too but $\textrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_2^2) \cong S_3$.

Comment: @SimonS there is no such group.

Comment: as @quid stated, the statement is true according to the mathoverflow article, but I am not sure how the proof would go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $G$ is finite abelian and not cyclic, it can be written as direct sum $G=G_1\oplus G_2\oplus\ldots \oplus G_n$ of $n\ge2$ nontrivial cyclic groups of orders dividing each other. Say $G_1\cong \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ and $G_2\cong \mathbb Z/md\mathbb Z$. As $G_1\oplus G_2$ is a direct summand, $\operatorname{Aut}(G_1\oplus G_2)$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$.
The group $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z/md\mathbb Z$ has especially the automorphisms $$\phi\colon (x+m\mathbb Z,y+md\mathbb Z)\mapsto (x+y+m\mathbb Z,y+md\mathbb Z)$$ and $$\psi\colon(x+m\mathbb Z,y+md\mathbb Z)\mapsto(x+\mathbb Z,y+dx+md\mathbb Z).$$
We have
$\psi(\phi(m\mathbb Z,1+md\mathbb Z))=(1+m\mathbb Z,1+d+md\mathbb Z)$ and $\phi(\psi(m\mathbb Z,1+md\mathbb Z))=(1+m\mathbb Z,1+md\mathbb Z)$. As $m>1$, this shows that $\operatorname{Aut}(G_1\oplus G_2)$ is not abelian.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.