# Why is $\text{Aut}(G_1 \oplus G_2)$ a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, direct-sum, automorphism-group

The answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302721/is-there-a-finite-abelian-group-g-such-that-textrmautg-is-abelian-but) states that $\text{Aut}(G_1 \oplus G_2)$ a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$, where $G$ has been decomposed in the invariant factors $G_1 \oplus G_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus G_n$. I do not see why this is true. Any hints would be appreciated.

EDIT: Would the reason be that there is an injective group homomorphism from $\text{Aut}(H)\oplus \text{Aut}(K)$ to $\text{Aut}(H \oplus K)$ (for groups $H, K$)?

Comment: Because any automorphism of G that fixes $G_1 \oplus G_2$ must also fix $G$.

Comment: @KennyLau Thanks for your answer. I'll have to think about this one, because it is not immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More precisely,

> $\text{Aut}(G_1 \oplus G_2)$ can be embedded into $\text{Aut}(G)$

Indeed, if $G=G_1 \oplus G_2 \oplus \ldots \oplus G_n$ and $\phi \in \text{Aut}(G_1 \oplus G_2)$, then $\phi \times id_3 \times \cdots \times id_n \in \text{Aut}(G)$.

Comment: thank you very much, I did not thought about this embedding when I wrote my question.